# Strange C++ delete[] statement in MS C++

Tags: c++, mfc, delete-operator

On some very old code base, we have this kind of statement:

```
delete [i+4] v;
```

Where `v` is indeed an array and `i` is an integer.

This code is in VS2010 but still compiles in VS2019. [Working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Y7n3as9Pq)

What's the meaning of this?  Is it, or was it something specific to Microsoft C++?

Comment: Please show a [mre]

Comment: `delete [i+4] v;` is invalid in C++.

Comment: @AnoopRana depends on what `v` actually is.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ what is the case when this compiles with a C++ compiler?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Yes, i have submitted a bug report [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/delete-2ptr-can-be-compiled-successful/10096688)

Comment: I suspect this might just be a compiler bug, you can put any value you like in there and it is just ignored, doesn't even need to be integral: https://godbolt.org/z/Y549Wz99r

Comment: I thought [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/381542/with-arrays-why-is-it-the-case-that-a5-5a) could apply.

Comment: @AlanBirtles Looks like it is not ignored, but rather evaluated and discarded https://godbolt.org/z/b4sWhManK

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili well yes, I meant that the value doesn't matter, verified by debugging and stepping into `delete` and checking that the pointer passed in is the same as the original pointer

Comment: Back in the olden days (i.e., cfront), you had to include the size of the array in the array delete statement. So `int *ptr = new int[10]; delete [10] ptr;`. I vaguely recall that the size argument might have been optional in C++98, but I don't have easy access to that standard, so I might just be hallucinating. It wasn't allowed in C++03.

Comment: @PeteBecker can't see it in [c++98](https://www.lirmm.fr/~ducour/Doc-objets/ISO+IEC+14882-1998.pdf)

Comment: @AlanBirtles -- thanks. It probably became optional in Cfront, because remembering the size was really annoying, and that backward-compatibility option went away with standardization.

Comment: @PeteBecker I assume that the parameter was needed for correctly calling destructors on all elements as cfront those days wouldn't want to try to retrieve array size information from underlying C compiler's array headers...

Comment: @Aconcagua -- that sounds right. One C++ compiler that I recall used a static lookup table to get the number of objects for `delete []`; others used the front of the allotted block. The first, of course, has serious issues for multi-threaded code, and nobody does it that way any more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`delete [i+4] v;` where `v` is pointing to a dynamic array that was created using `new` is **not vali**d in C++.

This seems to be a msvc bug which has been submitted [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/delete-2ptr-can-be-compiled-successful/10096688).

Comment: *'where [...]'* – that's not exclusive to such arrays, that's *always* invalid ;)

Comment: @Aconcagua I added the "where" part because [in this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72994189/strange-c-delete-statement-in-ms-c/72994414?noredirect=1#comment128923375_72994189) the user says that it depends. Also, note there was one more reason why i wrote the "where" part. Which is that in the question OP said that they have an array so i was talking in context of that. But yes it is invalid regardless.

Comment: As written it might, though, give the impression that this syntax is *only* in this situation invalid – thus I'd rather prefer wording like *'is illegal including the case where'* or similar. And actually id doesn't depend ;)

Comment: @Aconcagua Note i never said that it is limited to the case where `v` is an array. I only gave an example that was already given by OP. As you can see in this [bug report](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/delete-2ptr-can-be-compiled-successful/10096688) also.

Comment: No, you didn't, you just excluded the other cases from getting a statement on – which just *might* be interpreted as not applying there, at least leaves room for such interpretation... Just a hint for a *possible* improvement, don't say either that your answer would be *incorrect* as is ;)

Comment: It's only a bug if the compiler doesn't issue a diagnostic. That's the only requirement; having issued a diagnostic, the compiler is free to compile the code with an implemention-specific meaning. In this case, the compiler probably ignores the value. Passing a value is for backward compatibility with Cfront, where the value was required.

Comment: @PeteBecker Ok, thanks for letting me know. I wasn't aware of the point that if the compiler issues a diagnostic in this case then it won't be considered as a bug.

Comment: @AnoopRana -- just for completeness, "a diagnostic" is any of an implementation-defined set of messages issued by the compiler. Technically, a compiler that always writes "." to the console whenever you compile code conforms to the standard if "." is in the list of implementation-defined diagnostics. Beyond that, it's just a matter of quality of implementation. <g>

Comment: @PeteBecker I see. So this does mean that msvc is not standard conformant [here](https://godbolt.org/z/Y7n3as9Pq), right? I mean in this case msvc doesn't give any diagnostic.

Comment: @AnoopRana -- looks like it.

Comment: @AnoopRana Putting compiler flag `/W4` and a very clear diagnostic is issued, so the compiler is conformant: `<source>(4): warning C4208: nonstandard extension used: delete [exp] - exp evaluated but ignored`